# Google Actions Builder and Dialogflow CX?

Tags: google-assistant, dialogflow-cx

I would like to use Dialogflow CX to build an agent for the Google Assistant app but I am getting mixed information from articles and documentation on whether this is possible and how easy it is. Does anyone have experience doing this, or have any guidance on if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Google Assistant integration is not supported in the Dialogflow CX. Here are the supported [integrations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration) you can use in Dialogflow CX.

However, for any currently unsupported platforms, if they provide developer tools, you can create your own implementation using one of Dialogflow CX’s [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview), [Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3-overview) or [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc?hl=en).